# setting depths of movieclip to numbers from array

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a few movieclips on the stage, all the movieclipsnames are in an array
togheter with what should be the depth. i need a way to set the depths according
the numbers in the array.

sample
a$ = [{name:"item_name_1", depth: 10},{name:"item_name_2", depth: 11},{name:"item_name_3", depth: 12},{name:"item_name_4", depth: 13},{name:"item_name_5", depth: 14}]

i need something like:
set_depth(target_name, depth)

i know i can swap the depths with an other movieclip, but that results in wrong depth for some clips

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
   myArray.sortOn("depth", Array.NUMERIC);


    //assuming depth number means it is higher otherwise iterate in reverse
    for (var i:int = 0; i < myArray.length;i++)
    {
      addChild(myArray[i]);
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't matter. When you call addChild() it removes it if it exists and places back on top as the next item. This piece of code works, I have used it before ;-)